# Looping through a List of objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to loop through the student list which I received from a REST service located on a server. this list contains objects for students enrolled in a section. Each object has firstName, lastName, student ID and many other attributes, specifically an attribute called `isAbsent`. Its a Boolean value where it has true if the student is absent and false if the student is present in not absent. I want to store the students IDs who are absent (have `isAbsent=true`) in another String Array.

I tried this :

```
{ 
    //this array will store the IDs of students who are absent.
    $scope.selection = [];
    //$scope.studentList is the list of students for CRN=X and Date=Y
    for (id in $scope.studentList) {
        if ($scope.studentList.isAbsent === true) {
            $scope.selection.push($scope.studentList.id);
            console.log($scope.selection);
        }
    }
}
```

This code doesn't execute. I have no clue why, I guess the problem in the loop structure. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this will help?

```
for (var i=0;i<$scope.studentList.length;i++)
{
    if ($scope.studentList[i].isAbsent === true) 
    {
        $scope.selection.push($scope.studentList[i].id);
        console.log($scope.selection);
    }
}
```

p.s. don't use `for..in` with arrays. It will display an index instead of a value. It's not like C#.

Comment: It worked fine, but I need some clarifications: When I type studentList then followed by dot, I did not get the associated method "length" for this List. Does that mean we modified the prototype of the list?

Comment: 'm not sure i understand your question

Comment: I'm using Netbeans 8.0, I meant, that when I type studentList I expect to see dropdown suggestions list for the methods that are applied on this list, for example, studentList.getOwnPropertyNames() and        studentList.defineProperty() which are suggestion by the IDE. However, the method studentList.length doesn't show up in this list of suggestions.

Comment: IMHO netbeans is for java . not javascript. also - becuase $scope is a complex object ( very complex) - it's hard for autocomplete to realize  that studentList is array.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what browsers you need to support (e.g. IE >= 9), I'd suggest the newer [`foreach` construct](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). I find it easier to use:

```
$scope.studentList.forEach(function(value, index, array) {
    if (value.isAbsent === true) 
    {
        $scope.selection.push(value.id);
        console.log($scope.selection);
    }
});
```